# mp3 file not playing in Samsung Device but other Android device is ok

Tags: android, audio, audio-player, android-music-player

I used this code to play a mp3 file. Its playing in any device without Samsung... I search a lot but can't solved this problem. Please can anyone give any method to play mp3 in any device.

```
//Not working in Samsung Device
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
void playSound()
{
    try {
        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.recipe_tune);
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have any information related to an exception that is occurring, i notice you have a todo which suggests if an error occurs your ignoring it.

Answer (score 1):

Call prepare method before starting player and also print exception in your logcat and also catch like this,

```
try {
        //code lies here
 }

} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SecurityException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: _"Call prepare method before starting player"_  `public static MediaPlayer create (Context context, int resid)` Convenience method to create a `MediaPlayer` for a given resource id. **On success, `prepare()` will already have been called and must not be called again.**

Comment: Its not work...

The Exception is : java.lang.NullPointerException